# yii-boostrap doesn't load css or js files

Tags: php, css, twitter-bootstrap, yii

Trying to get yii boostrap to work.

In config/main.php

```
<?php

Yii::setPathOfAlias('bootstrap', dirname(__FILE__).'/../extensions/bootstrap');

return array(
    'basePath'   => dirname( __FILE__ ) . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . '..',
    'theme'=>'bootstrap',

    // preloading 'log' component
    'preload'    => array( 'log', ),

    // autoloading model and component classes
    'import'     => array(
        'application.models.*',
        'application.components.*',
        'application.modules.admin.models.*',
        'application.modules.admin.*',
    ),

    'modules'    => array(

        'gii'   => array(
            'class'     => 'system.gii.GiiModule',
            'password'  => 'xxx',
            // If removed, Gii defaults to localhost only. Edit carefully to taste.
            'ipFilters' => array( '127.0.0.1', '::1' ),
            'generatorPaths'=>array(
                'bootstrap.gii',
            ),
        ),

        'admin' => array(
            'components' => array(
                'user'=>array(
                    'class' => 'WebUser',
                    'allowAutoLogin'=>true,
                    'loginUrl' => array('/admin/login'),
                ),
            )
        ),
    ),

    // application components
    'components' => array(
        'bootstrap'=>array(
            'class'=>'bootstrap.components.Bootstrap',
        ),

        'user'         => array(
            'allowAutoLogin' => true,
        ),
        'urlManager'   => array(
            'urlFormat'      => 'path',
            'showScriptName' => false,
            'rules'          => array(
                '<controller:\w+>/<id:\d+>'              => '<controller>/view',
                '<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>/<id:\d+>' => '<controller>/<action>',
                '<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>'          => '<controller>/<action>',
            ),
        ),
        'db'=>array(
            'connectionString' => 'mysql:host=localhost;dbname=xxxx',
            'emulatePrepare' => true,
            'username' => 'xxx',
            'password' => 'xxx',
            'charset' => 'utf8',
        ),
        'errorHandler' => array(
            // use 'site/error' action to display errors
            'errorAction' => 'site/error',
        ),
        'log'          => array(
            'class'  => 'CLogRouter',
            'routes' => array(
                array(
                    'class'  => 'CFileLogRoute',
                    'levels' => 'error, warning',
                ),

                array(
                    'class' => 'CWebLogRoute',
                ),

            ),
        ),
    ),

    'params'     => array(
        // this is used in contact page
        'adminEmail' => 'webmaster@example.com',
    ),
);
```

in layouts/main.php

I have `Yii::app()->bootstrap->register();` which then throws an error

> include(Bootstrap.php): failed to open stream: No such file or
>   directory

`bootstrap.widgets` seem to be working as the proper code is generated, but what's missing is the css and js files to style everything correctly.

Comment: I advice you to use yiistrap with yiiwheels, it was made by the one who created yii boostrap and yiibooster, it has more functions and API to check when you don't know how to do something

Comment: is it just as painful to setup?

Comment: No, in the site they show you how to do it, however here I pasted my config file to use with yiistrap

Comment: the yiistrap extension should be under the extension's folder

Comment: also I remember that I have to change something inside a class , I think it was TBHTML or another alike, because it was trying to load something from the wrong route.

Comment: Thanks I'll give it a try, seems more robust that yii-bootstrap

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
return array(
    'basePath' => dirname(__FILE__) . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . '..',
    'name' => 'XXXXXX',
    // preloading 'log' component
    'preload' => array('log'),
    // autoloading model and component classes
    'import' => array(
        'application.models.*',
        'application.messages.*',
        'application.components.*',
        'application.extensions.bootstrap.helpers.*',
    ),
    'aliases' => array(
        'bootstrap' => realpath(__DIR__ . '/../extensions/bootstrap'), // change this if necessary
    ),
    'modules' => array(
        'gii' => array(
            'generatorPaths' => array('bootstrap.gii'),
        ),

//        'gii' => array(
//            'class' => 'system.gii.GiiModule',
//            'password' => 'XXXXXX',
//            // If removed, Gii defaults to localhost only. Edit carefully to taste.
//            'ipFilters' => array('XXXXXX'),
//        ),
    ),
    'components' => array(
        'user' => array(
            // enable cookie-based authentication
            'allowAutoLogin' => true,
        ),
        'bootstrap' => array(
            'class' => 'bootstrap.components.TbApi',
        ),
        // uncomment the following to enable URLs in path-format
        'urlManager' => array(
            'urlFormat' => 'path',
            'rules' => array(
                '<controller:\w+>/<id:\d+>' => '<controller>/view',
                '<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>/<id:\d+>' => '<controller>/<action>',
                '<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>' => '<controller>/<action>',

            ),
        ),
//        'db' => array(
//            'connectionString' => 'sqlite:' . dirname(__FILE__) . '/../data/testdrive.db',
//        ),
// uncomment the following to use a MySQL database

          'db'=>array(
          'connectionString' => 'mysql:host=localhost;dbname=XXXXXXe',
          'emulatePrepare' => true,
          'username' => 'XXXXX',
          'password' => 'XXXXX',
          'charset' => 'utf8',
          ),

        'errorHandler' => array(
            // use 'site/error' action to display errors
            'errorAction' => 'site/error',
        ),
        'log' => array(
            'class' => 'CLogRouter',
            'routes' => array(
                array(
                    'class' => 'CFileLogRoute',
                    'levels' => 'error, warning',
                ),
            // uncomment the following to show log messages on web pages
            /*
              array(
              'class'=>'CWebLogRoute',
              ),
             */
            ),
        ),
    ),
    // application-level parameters that can be accessed
    // using Yii::app()->params['paramName']
    'params' => array(
        // this is used in contact page
        'adminEmail' => 'webmaster@example.com',
    ),
);
```

Comment: Thank you, for the recored all I had to do was add the `aliases` reference to bootstrap in my config to make this work